# Maven surefire suiteXmlFile possibilities

Tags: maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

For the moment I have the possibility to run multiple tests on maven with the surefire plugin like this :

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=test1.xml,test2.xml,test3.xml,test4.xml,...
```

It is nice but I would like to know if it's possible to improve it by having the possibility of reading a file that contains these `test.xml`.

I would like to do this to improve readability since the path to these tests can be pretty long.

So instead of that I would like to do something like this :

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=file.txt
```

and inside my `file.txt`:

```
path/to/my/test1.xml,path/to/my/test2.xml,path/to/my/test3.xml,...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to use the properties plugin:

**Plugin**

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>${propertiesFile}</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

**Properties File**

```
test.files = path/to/my/test1.xml,path/to/my/test2.xml,path/to/my/test3.xml
```

**Surefire**

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>${test.files}</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

**Command**

```
mvn -DpropertiesFile=props.txt properties:read-project-properties clean test
```

Comment: Hey how do you define the path to the properties File ?

Comment: Where do you set these variables : ${propertiesFile} && ${test.files}

Comment: i have updated the mvn command.. try now. test.files is defined in properties file